# Chainer : Exception in main training loop: out of memory to allocate 2097152000 bytes (total 13850445312 bytes)

Tags: python-3.x, memory-management, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, chainer

Chainer Training code:

```
 I am using --
 Chainer: 6.0.0
 NumPy: 1.15.4
 CuPy:
     CuPy Version          : 6.0.0
     CUDA Root             : /usr/local/cuda-10.0
     CUDA Build Version    : 10000
     CUDA Driver Version   : 10010
     CUDA Runtime Version  : 10000
     cuDNN Build Version   : 7401
     cuDNN Version         : 7401
     NCCL Build Version    : 2307
     NCCL Runtime Version  : 2307
     iDeep: 2.0.0.post3

 AwS P2.xlarge Instances : Gpu k80 with Memory 11441MiB
```

I checked Memory getting full -

```
   nvidia-smi -l 1
```

My question is this Problem in source code ? OR Genuinely all Memory  gets full ? How to resolve it ?

I am following [CHAINER VAE](https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/examples/vae/net.py)

*Everything work's on CPU* .*It takes time,hence running on gpu is required*.

I tried reducing batch_size from 100 to 50,but as I mentioned *8068MiB / 11441MiB* memory is consume when I execute the line

```
  avg_elbo_loss.to_gpu() .
```

Secondly,I changed it to cpu

```
  avg_elbo_loss.to_cpu().
```

but same happen when I execute the updater

```
  updater = training.StandardUpdater(train_iter, optimizer, device=args.gpu)
```

Now, if I execute any more line with *args.gpu* then it throws OOM(out of memory)

I applied again to use higher instances like p2.8xlarge.But, if it is the problem in source code,I have to know before shifting to other instances.

```
prior = network.make_prior(args.dim_z)
avg_elbo_loss = network.AvgELBOLoss(encoder, decoder, prior,
                            beta=args.beta, k=args.k)
```

*This below line take around 8068MiB / 11441MiB*

```
avg_elbo_loss.to_gpu()
```

*There are more line of code that requires memory which when executed throws an OOM*

```
updater = training.StandardUpdater(train_iter, optimizer, device=args.gpu)

trainer.extend(extensions.Evaluator(test_iter,avg_elbo_loss , device=args.gpu))
```

*And at last for training*

```
trainer.run()

 File "cupy/core/core.pyx", line 134, in cupy.core.core.ndarray.__init__
 File "cupy/cuda/memory.pyx", line 518, in cupy.cuda.memory.alloc
 File "cupy/cuda/memory.pyx", line 1085, in 
 cupy.cuda.memory.MemoryPool.malloc
 File "cupy/cuda/memory.pyx", line 1106, in 
 cupy.cuda.memory.MemoryPool.malloc
 File "cupy/cuda/memory.pyx", line 919, in 
 cupy.cuda.memory.SingleDeviceMemoryPool.malloc
 File "cupy/cuda/memory.pyx", line 949, in 
 cupy.cuda.memory.SingleDeviceMemoryPool._malloc
 File "cupy/cuda/memory.pyx", line 697, in cupy.cuda.memory._try_malloc
```

*Will finalize trainer extensions and updater before reraising the exception.*

Is there anyway to solve it ?

I expected it to run, without out of memory problem.

Comment: I tried to work with 8 GPU's,found out that from gpu (0-7)  consume the 8068MiB / 11441MiB one after the other,so on executing the updater all 8 gpu' consumed 8068MiB / 11441MiB .So executing further again lead to Out of Memory problem.I cannot understand which part is causing the problem and why ?

Comment: Same problem was solved with chainer 5.4.0 when I was using 8 gpu's from p2.8xlarge Instances.

Comment: I have tried reducing Batch_Size down to single digit.

Comment: And, it works completely fine using CPU.Since,it takes time I need to get it run on gpu.

Comment: I am out of Ideas to solve this problem.@chainer @cupy